# Strange ^M characters appears in Github after pushing code

Tags: git, flutter, android-studio, github

[image]

Hello, I see "^M" displayed at the end of each line when pushing my code to GitHub. The strange thing is that they appear only for a rare set of files, in most cases files are displayed correctly. I tried using cli and Android Studio build in VCS integration to push code, but every time I see the same result.
Has anyone experienced the same problem?

Comment: That's indicative of a line ending problem.  You probably saved your files with Windows line endings or maybe with mixed line endings.

Comment: @jamesdlin: it is indeed line-endings but these are ancient macOS (from mac OS 9, pre-X, mid-1980s / early 1990s era) line endings rather than Windows line endings. How the OP got *this* setting, I have no idea.

Comment: I am using macOS 12.0.1